# Is there a way to avoid size specifications on android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I work with Android daily, and I would like to avoid the specifications of the views size.
For example, if I make a `TextView`, I got to assign Height and Width properties, like this:

```
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/activity_lbl"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Again -->
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!--Again...  --> /> 

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/activity_lbl2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Again... -->
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!--Again, for ever  --> />
```

And for every view I create, I got to assign the same size specifications.
Is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: From the docs for layout_width and layout_height: "Specifies the basic width of the view. This is a required attribute for any view inside of a containing layout manager." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare it within a style that you'll apply in your layout files like this:

File: res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="wrapall">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And then apply it to your layouts like this:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/activity_lbl"
      style="@style/wrapall" /> 

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/activity_lbl2"
      style="@style/wrapall" />
```

Comment: I would encourage this method since you may, in the future, want to set all of the text views' text size or color.

Answer (score -2):

you can't avoid the

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

because it's important but i'm going to give you some codes for some layouts
for images you can use this in your class:

```
ImageView.getLayoutParams().height = YourHeightValue ;
    ImageView.getLayoutParams().width = YourWidthValue;
```

for the textView use the `Textview.setSize(); or TextView.setwidth(int); TextView.setHeight(int);`

Comment: Why would you add style attributes in Java to something defined in XML?

Comment: Sorry, I meant why would you add a static (non changing) attribute in Java?